# .htaccess: Redirect to requested uri

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, litespeed

I have LiteSpeed web server and LScache running. For this I want to improve request times. LiteSpeed web server is Apache compatible and supports almost all Apache directive, so for my need it doesn't matter if it is LiteSpeed or Apache regarding redirect .htaccess rules. What I want to do is to define a redirection rule to the requested URI if a certain cookie doesn't exist.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !ls_smartpush [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ the_requested_uri.com/? [R=302,L]
```

Is there any way to use the requested URI as a variable and to use this variable for redirection location?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ the_requested_uri.com/? [R=302,L]`  are you trying to make it like `https://example.com/something.html` to be redirected into `something.html.com`???

Comment: No, something.html -> something.html as requested

Answer (score 0):

you can capture it from your rewrite rule pattern

in your example rule  `^(.*)$` will be captured as the requested URI

e.g    https://example.com/something.html  ->  it will be `something.html` , and you can use it as `$1` in your rule

you can also enable debug log on LSWS, it will log out how exactly it interpreted the rewritecond/rewriterule and what it redirected into , for debug